# Best data structure for key-value with index

Tags: android, data-structures, android-recyclerview, key-value

I am using a RecyclerView where each row is always associated with two String objects: a row title String and a data String (used when row is clicked).

Currently, I am using two separate arrays to supply my recyclerview/adapter setup with this data. However, I want to clean up my approach and use a single data structure that can associate the row title String and the data String.

My initial thought for this is a (Linked)HashMap, but the RecyclerView.Adapter uses position index so I don't think this is the best approach.

Can someone recommend a data structure for me to use here? Hopefully, something nice is available in the Java or Android libraries that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom data structure and store it in ArrayList. For RecyclerView any DataStructure with time complexity of O(1) is a good choice.

You can do following

```
public class DataModel {
    private final String title;
    private final String dataString;
    public DataModel(final String title, final String dataString){
        this.title = title;
        this.dataString = dataString;
    }
    // Create getter methods
}
```

Then you can use it in Adapter as follows:

```
final List<DataModel> dataModelList = new ArrayList<>();
```